# Disable text fields depending upon the value in other text field retrieved using LOV in oracle forms

Tags: oracleforms

i have a form wherein i accept id of a customer and depending upon that id i retrieve details of that particular customer.
Over here i have a LOV for payment modes.
If the customer is paying by cheque, i have kept fields to accept cheque details.
But if he enters cash, i disable the cheque details fields.

Now the thing is, when i am entering new record and i select cash as payment mode, the cheque details fields are disabled. But when i save that record, the cheque details fields are again enabled.

Also when i retrieve the data from database using 'execute-query' the fields are not disabled if the payment mode is cash for that particular customer.

I want to keep the cheque details fields disabled whenever the value in the payment mode field is CASH.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: [edit] & and show your code. Search for instances where you're disabling and see if it gets executed when you do an execute query. Hard to say without more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this do the following:
1. Write a procedure in program unit to disable that fields and call that procedure on payment mode field's when_validate trigger or key_next_item trigger, below is the example:

if :block1.payment_mode = 'CASH' then
       disable_fields; -- disable item procedure
    end if;

2. In block level write when-new-record-instance trigger to call that procedure to disable the fields if payment mode is cash, below is the example:

when-new-record-instance trigger code:

```
if :block1.payment_mode = 'CASH' then
   disable_fields; -- disable item procedure
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

when u save the record then record status is changed to query mode.. so for showing the cheq detail fields disabled after saving and when you query the record:
(1) Disable the fields programmatically in Form Level Trigger KEY-EXEQRY

```
 if :block1.payment_mode = 'CASH' then
      set_item_property('BLOCK.Field',Update_allowed,Property_false); 
      Set_item_property('BLOCK.Field',insert_ALLOWED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
  end if;
```

(2) copy the same code for disabling the fields in Form Level Trigger WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE